# Need a procedure to determine the distance between two 2D points: Sqrt ((x1 - x2)^2 + (Yi - Y2)^2)

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(lambda (x0 x1 y0 y1) 
    (let ((xdiff(-x0 x1) 
        (ydiff(-y0 y1)))
    (sqrt(+(*xdiff xdiff)
           (*ydiff ydiff)))))))
```

where do I add the code to ask the user to put in the values for x1, x2, y1, y2?

Comment: Hint: use `read` to ask for each of the input values. And put your code inside a named procedure, so you can pass it the values you read.

Comment: First give that a name and fix the errors. Then you can retrieve input *outside* this procedure.